# Matching url with special begin and end

Tags: regex, url

First of all I'm trying to learn regex so if it can be better, you're free to correct it..

But what I want is to match URLs that not start with "{" and end with "|". I tried to make one and this is the best what I could:

```
^((?!{)((((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)|(www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.:#/~}?]+)(?=\|))
```

The regex only matches urls that don't start with a "{" and end with a "|". I tried to negate the (?=\|) part but then it doesn't match anything...

**Edit**

Urls that need to match the regex:

```
hey this url www.test.com needs to match
http://test.com
{www.thissiteneedstomatchtoo.com}
```

Urls that are not allowed to match:

```
{www.test.com|title of my page}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add an anchor to the end of the line `$`
- Negate the lookahead assertion `(?!)`
- Escape the dot after www `\.`

so your regex becomes:

```
^((?!{)((((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)|(www\.))[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.:#/~}?]+)(?!\|))$
                             __^                          __^  __^
```

**edit**

New version according to comment:

```
((?<!{)((((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)|(www\.))[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.:#/~}?]++)(?!\|))
                                            note this __^^
```

`++` : match at least 1 time, but as many times as possible

some tests:

```
www.domain.com : OK -> www.domain.com
http://domain.com : OK -> http://domain.com
{www.domain.com : KO
www.domain.com| : KO
{www.domain.com| : KO
text text www.domain.com text text : OK -> www.domain.com
text texthttp://domain.com text text : OK -> http://domain.com
text text{www.domain.comtext text : KO
text textwww.domain.com|text text : KO
text text{www.domain.com|text text : KO
```

to match also `{www.thissiteneedstomatchtoo.com}`, you can use:

```
((?<={)?((((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)|(www\.))[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.:#/~}?]++)(?!\|))
```

but it'll match `{www.domain.com`

```
www.domain.com : OK -> www.domain.com
http://domain.com : OK -> http://domain.com
{www.domain.com : OK -> www.domain.com
www.domain.com| : KO
{www.domain.com| : KO
text text www.domain.com text text : OK -> www.domain.com
text texthttp://domain.com text text : OK -> http://domain.com
text text{www.domain.com text text : OK -> www.domain.com
text textwww.domain.com|text text : KO
text text{www.domain.com|text text : KO
hey this url www.test.com needs to match : OK -> www.test.com
http://test.com : OK -> http://test.com
{www.thissiteneedstomatchtoo.com} : OK -> www.thissiteneedstomatchtoo.com}
{www.test.com|title of my page} : KO
```

Comment: @Vince V.: could you provide some samples that match and not match ?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I think that will be sufficient :)

Answer (score 2):

The regex pattern you provided can be improved. It matches invalid URLs, e.g. `http://www.abc...com`

You can find several different patterns for URL matching on [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL).

Comment: I apologize for the mistake, it's fixed now.